# How can I transfer columns of a table to rows in python?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

One ID can have multiple dates and results and I want each date and result column stacked sideways to be stacked into 1 date and 1 result row. How can I transfer columns of a table to rows?

[Table which needs to be transposed]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piHIU.png)

[I want to change like this]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeJyH.png)

Comment: kindly post data as text, not pics

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, not sure if it's the best solution:

```
    df2 = pd.concat([df.loc[:,['ID','Date','Result']],
             df.loc[:,['ID','Date1','Result1']].rename(columns={'Date1':'Date','Result1':'Result'}),
             df.loc[:,['ID','Date2','Result2']].rename(columns={'Date2':'Date','Result2':'Result'})
            ]).dropna().sort_values(by = 'ID')
```

It's just separating the dataframes, concatenating them together inline, removing the NAs and then sorting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to transpose data from pandas you could use [pandas.DataFrame.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) There are more examples there on the syntax.